# Is parameter expansion on $@ not supported by the sh shell?

Tags: bash, shell, dash

I posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039653/283843) to a question on AU, and I found that parameter expansion on `$@` doesn't work with the `sh` shell:

```
<infile xargs -d'\n' sh -c 'echo "${@%%/*}"' _
```

but it works fine in `bash`. Is this expected behavior of the `sh` shell, and how can I perform expansion there?

Additionally, I know that with the `-n1` option of `xargs` I can pass only one line to the command at a time, but I was interested in whether `sh` can expand `$@`:

```
<infile xargs -d'\n' -n1 sh -c 'echo "${0%%/*}"'
```

`infile` contains:

```
A1 /B1/C1
A 2/B2/C2
A3/B3/C3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep, dash appears to be less than useful here. Though it's not at fault, strictly speaking, as `${@%...}` is [unspecified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> The following four varieties of parameter expansion provide for substring processing. [...] If parameter is '`#`', '`*`', or '`@`', the result of the expansion is unspecified.

It's weird though, it seems that if an expansion like that modifies the end of one positional parameter, it drops the following ones. But not if it doesn't actually modify the end:

```
$ dash -c 'set -- foo bar; printf "<%s>\n" "${@%o}";'
<fo>
$ dash -c 'set -- foo bar; printf "<%s>\n" "${@%x}";'
<foo>
<bar>
$ dash -c 'set -- foo bar doo; printf "<%s>\n" "${@%r}";'
<foo>
<ba>
```

Bash, ksh and Zsh all seem to handle `"${@#...}"` and `"${@%...}"` by processing each positional parameter independently, which would seem the useful thing to do.

I suppose the obvious workaround for `dash` is to make the modification one argument at a time:

```
for x in "$@"; do echo "${x%%/*}"; done
```

---

For what it's worth, the behaviour of the prefix/suffix removal expansions used on `$*` also varies between shells. Bash and ksh seem to modify the parameters first and join them after that, while Zsh and dash join the parameters first and modify the concatenated string:

```
$ zsh -c 'set -- ax bx; printf "<%s>\n" "${*%%x*}";'
<a>
$ bash -c 'set -- ax bx; printf "<%s>\n" "${*%%x*}";'
<a b>
```

Comment: sounds `sh` thinks `$@` is a single parameter for whole file (or will break to multiple if exceed ARG_MAX) and do expansion on the only argument.

Comment: Also note that pdksh and derivatives give you a `Bad substitution` error on that code. For `${*%pattern}`, you see some variation in behaviour in things like `"$shell" -c 'printf "<%s>\n" "${*%x*}"' sh ax by`

Comment: @αғsнιη, it's not that simple. note the second example where the expansion leaves the positional parameters as separate words. And I don't think `ARG_MAX` comes into it, that processing is internal to the shell.